# C++, вопрос про безопасность offsetof

Tags: c++, выравнивание

Я бы хотел прояснить следующий момент.

По Стандартам `C` и `C++` разыменование указателя, который содержит адрес с неверным для данного типа выравниванием, - есть неопределенное поведение.

Более того, даже запись в указатель адреса с неверным выравниванием - тоже неопределенное поведение.

Благословенный способ получения данных, чье выравнивание больше единицы (`int`, `float` и пр.), из невыровненного расположения, - это использование `memcpy()`. Этот способ устраняет из кода неопределенное поведение, а вызов функции компилятор заменяет на прямое помещение в регистр, если это возможно.

Я не понял одного - каков безопасный способ получить величину смещения для заданного поля?

Мне известно про существование `offsetof()`. И этот способ гарантированно был бы безопасен, если бы это была `buildin` функция, но в моем компиляторе это не так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из кода, этот макрос содержит разыменование нулевого указателя. Как компилятор это учитывает и учитывает ли? Или это костыль, на надежность которого полагаться не стоит?

Comment: Боюсь вас разочаровать, но `memcpy()` (о которой знает компилятор (g++)) в некоторых ситуациях работает с ошибкой (exception при записи по невыровненному адресу (почему-то авторы компайлера посчитали, что такое невозможно)). Т.о. от нынешних компайлеров можно ожидать чего угодно

Comment: @avp, это же очевидно просто баг в какой-то версии/на какой-то архитектуре... а от багов панацеи пока ни кто не придумал... или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, все верно, на определенной архитектуре (с выключенным кэшем, в BareMetal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я не понял одного - каков безопасный способ получить величину смещения для заданного поля?

Возьмите готовый объект данного типа и вычисляйте на здоровье. При наличии готового объекта, вам не придется заниматься работой с невалидными указателями. Это неудобно, но формально является безопасным способом.

> Как видно из кода, этот макрос содержит разыменование нулевого указателя.

Реализация `offsetof` находится внутри реализации стандартной библиотеки. Правила языков С и С++ на эту территории не распространяются. Это вообще не С и не С++. Разглядывать реализацию `offsetof` с точки зрения требований C++ - бессмысленное занятие.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.